# How to use Assignment expressions and typing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

[PEP-0572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) has introduced Assignment expressions feature. And I'm currious how to use it with typing expressions?

Lets take an example from the PEP's page:

```
if result := solution(xs, n):
    # use result
```

And add type of value that we want to use:

```
from typing import Dict
if result:Dict := solution(xs, n):
    # use result
```

It will fail with SyntaxError.

Is there way to use typing for such expressions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [PEP explicitly says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#id14):

> Inline type annotations are not supported:
>
> `p: Optional[int] = None`
>
> # Closest equivalent is `p: Optional[int]` as a separate declaration

So, for your example:

```
from typing import Dict

result: Dict
if result := solution(xs, n):
    # use result
```